# Facebook restFB : Unsupported get request. Object with ID 'me' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, restfb

My facebook app is approved and has publish_pages, manage_pages permissions approved.

Everything worked fine till yesterday. I am seeing the below exception on the following line

Connection myPages = facebookClient.fetchConnection("/me/accounts", Page.class);

Anyone having similar issues ?

```
com.restfb.exception.FacebookGraphException: Received Facebook error response of type GraphMethodException: Unsupported get request. Object with ID 'me' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api (code 100, subcode 33) 'null - null'
    com.restfb.exception.generator.DefaultFacebookExceptionGenerator$DefaultGraphFacebookExceptionMapper.exceptionForTypeAndMessage(DefaultFacebookExceptionGenerator.java:187)
    com.restfb.exception.generator.DefaultFacebookExceptionGenerator.throwFacebookResponseStatusExceptionIfNecessary(DefaultFacebookExceptionGenerator.java:61)
    com.restfb.DefaultFacebookClient.makeRequestAndProcessResponse(DefaultFacebookClient.java:833)
    com.restfb.DefaultFacebookClient.makeRequest(DefaultFacebookClient.java:755)
    com.restfb.DefaultFacebookClient.makeRequest(DefaultFacebookClient.java:717)
    com.restfb.DefaultFacebookClient.fetchConnection(DefaultFacebookClient.java:245)
```

Comment: can you check the user access token with the access token debugger and please check the user, maybe she is disabled. And please check the call, according to Facebook this happens for some apps and fixes "itself". https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/1193907164287095/

Comment: Thank you @Norbert. We are still experiencing the issue, hopefully it will get fixed by tomorrow. Tested access token and it seems good. No issue with user too, tried on different user and getting same issue. I am guessing something is messed up on FB side during the update of the Standard and Extended permission setup.